# How Bold Works in Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

How Ckeditor Bold works (code) so that i am able to use/create code which provide the same functionality while making plug-in, which is use to insert and remove the custom-tag in the source

Answer (score 2):

[Basicstyles](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js)  plugin is responsible for that. It creates [CKEDITOR.styleCommand](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.styleCommand) commands that use [editor.applyStyle](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-applyStyle) and [editor.removeStyle](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-removeStyle). Those methods depend on [style.applyToRange](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-method-applyToRange) which applies styles of different types. What should be interesting for you is the internal [applyInlineStyle](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/style.js#L448-L703) method. This is, however, hundreds LOC.

Still you can use the API to apply own styles to the content. Hope this helps.